# Vulnerability of serial self-hashing

Tags: passwords, md5, password-hash

Is there any vulnerability associated with self-hashing?

Let's say I want to keep a database of md5-hashed passwords. The issue is that most people will use easy pws like 'password', 'admin' etc., all prime candidates for reverse md5 lookup services. My idea is to hash the hash i.e.:

```
password  = 'admin'
md5(password) = 0x21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
md5(md5(password)) = 0xc3284d0f94606de1fd2af172aba15bf3
```

In real-life examples we use salts. But is the above even a bad idea, does it really bring inherent flaws?

Comment: Yes, it is a *very* bad idea. unsalted, vulnerable to rainbow tables, very fast to implement in GPUs for bruteforcing, and the hash is so easy that a laptop can run dictionary attacks on it. unless you're a cryptographer, do not invent your own hashing scheme, use bcrypt.

Comment: OK but so there is no other vulnerability than the fact it's easily precomputable? Does that mean cracking 'hellobatteryhorseshoefriend' would be unfeasible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any scheme you might come up with yourself to store passwords is inherently less secure than using one of the schemes specifically designed by cryptographers for password storage. There are a lot of potential vulnerabilities with hashing schemes which can be prevented that way, including susceptibility to brute-force attacks or dictionary attacks, mathematical issues resulting in a weakening of the hash function (e.g. with MD5) and other issues.

Specifically, MD5 (even with a Salt or multiple rounds) is trivially insecure so that even "good" passwords can be broken by just brute-force in seconds. **You should never store passwords hashed with MD5 anywhere!**

As an example, with [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) on my notebook, I can brute-force about 1.8 billion MD5 hashes per second. This number can be significantly increased my several magnitudes by using one or more GPUs or by leveraging more knowledge about the passwords (e.g. with pre-computed rainbow tables or by using variations of dictionary words).

Thus, instead of using a generic hash function, you should always use a modern hash algorithm designed for password storage, specifically, one of these:

- Argon2
- Scrypt
- Bcrypt
- PBKDF2

Each of these algorithms was specifically designed for password hashing, i.e. to be "slow" to not allow easy and/or cheap brute-force attacks.

There are mature libraries supporting any these algorithms for most languages available. If in doubt, try to use a libsodium-based library for your programming language. In general, you should use the secure solutions available for your programming language or framework instead of inventing your own schemes.

See https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/password_hashing for details about the challenges of password hashing and available modern solutions.

Comment: OK I was specifically looking for an explanation as to why it's a bad idea, not so much alternatives :)

Comment: See the updates to my answer. Still, please be aware that MD5 should not be used anywhere. Even as a regular hash function (for data, not passwords), it has been entirely broken many years ago. With MD5, you can e.g. easily find collisions (that is multiple different input strings resulting in the same hash) which can cause a lot of issues in real-world systems.

Comment: btw if you're using md5 for speed, use blake2b instead - it's even faster than md5, but offers security similar to SHA3. (don't use any of these hashes for passwords, though)

Answer (score 0):

Double hashing is often supported out of the box by password crackers, have a look at [hashcat's Algorithms](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/#features-algos) section.

Even with a more clever scheme you should be aware that one can brute-force about [100 Giga MD5 per second](https://www.blackhillsinfosec.com/hashcat-benchmarks-nvidia-gtx-1080ti-gtx-1070-hashcat-benchmarks/) with a good GPU. If you are interested in more indepth information, you can have a look at my [tutorial](https://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about secure password storage.